# adjusting table columns

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to make table with text (this is for a medieval roleplaying).

```
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l }
Delikt & Leichte Strafe & Mittlere Strafe & Schwere Strafe \\
Angriff auf einen Geweihten & Brandzeichnung & Blendung oder Abschneiden von Zungen oder Hand & Tod \\
Anstiftung zu Aufruhr &  Brandzeichnung & Tod &  Tod durch Rädern \\
Aufwiegelung & Bis zu 10 Stockhiebe & Pranger & Verbannung \\
\end{tabular}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

How can I create equal columns? In MS Word, columns can be adjusted so that they are all the same width, but is this possible with LaTeX as well?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use the `tabularx` environment and the `X` column type. If it has to be more than one page long, use `xltabular` instead, so that it can break across pages.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's very simple: the table preamble is `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}` to have  4 equal columns.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prescribe column widths with `p` (or `m` and `b`) columns type. For example, you can write your table as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9em}} }
Delikt  & Leichte Strafe & Mittlere Strafe & Schwere Strafe \\
Angriff auf einen Geweihten 
        & Brandzeichnung 
            & Blendung oder Abschneiden von Zungen oder Hand 
                & Tod \\
Anstiftung zu Aufruhr 
        &  Brandzeichnung 
            & Tod 
                &  Tod durch Rädern \\
Aufwiegelung 
        & Bis zu 10 Stockhiebe 
            & Pranger 
                & Verbannung \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

As you can see, in this cases long text in cells are broken into more lines.

**original answer**
However, see, if use of the `tabularray` package with library `siunitx` gives acceptable (nicer) result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
    \label{tab:c}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l, wd=5em] *{3}{Q[c, wd=5em, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
        & {{{Item 1}}} 
                & {{{Item 2}}} 
                    & {{{Item 3}}}  \\  
Group1  & 0.8   & 0.1   & 0.1       \\
Group2  & 0.1   & 0.8   & 0.1       \\
Group3  & 0.1   & 0.1   & 0.8       \\
Group4  & 0.34  & 0.33  & 0.33      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Ups, I wrongly replicate table from answer of @WinnieNotThePooh. Well, it may serv as skeleton for a some similar table with numbers which you like to align at their decimal points.

With your table, which fragment you show in question, a possible solution using `tabularray` package, can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
    \label{tab:c}
\begin{tblr}{ colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{4}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight]} @{}},
              row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
Delikt  & Leichte Strafe 
                & Mittlere Strafe 
                        & Schwere Strafe        \\
    \midrule
Angriff auf einen Geweihten
        & Brandzeichnung
                & Blendung oder Abschneiden von Zungen oder Hand
                        & Tod                   \\
Anstiftung zu Aufruhr
        &  Brandzeichnung
                & Tod   &  Tod durch Rädern     \\
Aufwiegelung
        & Bis zu 10 Stockhiebe
                & Pranger
                        & Verbannung            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The compilation result is:

[image]

Better filling of textyou will get if you will reduce font size in table to `\small` (by adding this command after `\begin{table}`). In this case table will looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. One problem though: I get this error:

File `tabularray.sty' not found.

I am using TexLive2020 and it should be installed. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Brayanokles, sorry, but I'm not familiar with TeXlive. Package is relative new (from the end 2020, but recent version is from March this year), so it is possible that is not part of your TeXlive. Try to install it manually. At Jun 1st, will be available new version 2022B.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook) **example 4.12**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Vertical and lateral stresses of mortar.}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X | X | X | X|}
\hline
& Item1 & Item2 & Item3 \\ \hline
Group1 & 0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
Group2 & 0.1 & 0.8 & 0.1 \\
Group3 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.8 \\
Group4 & 0.34 & 0.33 & 0.33 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{c}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I would prescribe smaller table width, for example `0.5\textwidth` and table centered in the `table` float environment.

Comment: @Brayanokles if it's really helped You, mark it as usefull, please

Comment: That's the green thing on the left?